# How to directly call the Handlerbars View helper with a ContainerView in Ember 1.8

Tags: ember.js

I have a Handlebars helper that returns a ContainerView that has some complex logic for auto generating forms. Before Ember 1.8, this helper worked fine, but now I get this assertion error:

`Assertion Failed: <(subclass of Ember.ContainerView):ember406> must be a subclass of Ember.View, not <(subclass of Ember.ContainerView):ember406>`

Here is the helper itself:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('render-form', function(form_name, options) {

    // FF is a library that generates the ContainerView
    var form = new FF.Form(form_name),

        // View contains the result of Ember.ContainerView.extend({...}).create()
        view = form.getView(); 

    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, view, options);
});
```

Ember 1.8 has deprecated support for global view lookups, but still supports getting views via bindings.   Does anyone know how to call the view helper such that the ContainerView will be rendered?